# Call methods of specific other object

Tags: java

I want to create an object that is linked in some way to another object of the same class. This link should be specified in the constructor of the new object.

```
public class Counter {
    public Counter(){
     // default counter constructor
    }

    public Counter(Counter oldCounter){
     // do stuff specifying new object is linked to oldCounter
    }

    public void someMethod(){
    // this method should call a method belonging to oldCounter
        oldCounter.someOtherMethod();
    }
```

Tried searching the archives for an answer, but couldn't find anything...

Comment: Your code does what you say you want to do (assuming you save the argument you give the constructor somewhere). What is your question?

Comment: How do I 'save the argument'? How do I specify the link in the constructor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember the argument as a private instance member, then use that member:

```
public class Counter {
    // The instance member we'll use, note that we initialize it to `null`
    // because you have a zero-args constructor, so we want to be sure we
    // know whether we have one or not
    private Counter otherCounter = null;

    public Counter() {}

    public Counter(Counter oldCounter) {
        // Remember it here
        this.otherCounter = oldCounter;
    }

    public void someMethod() {
        // Use it here
        if (this.otherCounter != null) {
            this.otherCOunter.someOtherMethod();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To achieve what you want Crowder's answer is good enough.

You are having two version of same class. For me it seems that you need to follow some design pattern to  better organize your code. In this case Factory Pattern may be a good choice.